# Music Playlist for a website

Tags: xml, database, mpmusicplayercontroller, audio-player

I have a pretty simple question. I'm debating whether a music playlist should be stored using XML or a Database... The details of roughly what im doing are stated below:

1. The music playlist is depending on a registered user meaning that each user has his own playlist
2. If stored in a DB it can be referenced to each user through his userID
3. If stored in XML each user will have his own XML file storing his personal playlist
4. **The playlist should be secure so people cant get the url of the audio file for download**

I think thats about it pretty basic non the less please provide your opinion and reason for your choice this way i can evaluate my options and select the best one. Thank you for your help!!

**EDIT**
Added one more detail

Answer (score 0):

Cool Idea but when using Xml::your project would be a bit safe and faster to search through
When using Mysql you need to create lots of tables which would use hirrectial relation. observe Youtube well...

Comment: It would help if you could explain your answer a bit more.